# SQL server 2008 default user name

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I just installed a new `Microsoft Visual Studio - 2010`, with this studio `SQL server` also

installed  and at the time of installation i added a password but i didn`t add the username.

So i want to know what is the default user name it SQL server 2008 using ?

Answer (score 3):

default user for SQL Server authentication  is `sa`

Answer (score 2):

The default username would be `sa`.

Think of this like the `Administrator` account on windows or the `root` account on a UNIX box.  Use it to create another admin account that you'll use for regular tasks, then either disable it or set an obscenely long password for it and use it only when necesseary.

Comment: And it is recommended to add other users and disable SA as soon as possible.